# msbuild task in NAnt does not compile WiX project in Postbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, wix, nant, signtool

This WiX Setup project compiles in Visual Studio without a problem.

However, running it in NAnt using the msbuild task shows the following error.

msbuild task:

```
<msbuild project="App_Installers\App.Setup\App.Setup.wixproj">
        <property name="Configuration" value="Release"/>
        <property name="target" value="Rebuild"/>
        <property name="verbosity" value="Normal"/>
       <property name="SolutionDir" value="${build.dir}"/>
</msbuild>
```

Postbuild event that fails:

```
"$(SolutionDir)\App_Tools\Signing Certificate\signtool.exe" sign /f "$(SolutionDir)\App_Tools\Signing Certificate\Comodo_Company_Signing_Certificate.pfx" /p password /d "Company Consulting" "$(ProjectDir)obj\$(PlatformName)\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetPath)"
```

Error message SignOutput:

```
  [msbuild]
  [msbuild] "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Installers\R
oCo.Setup\App.Setup.wixproj" (default target) (1) ->
  [msbuild] "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.c
sproj" (default target) (39) ->
  [msbuild] (PostBuildEvent target) ->
  [msbuild]   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.t
argets(4291,5): error MSB3073: The command ""E:\Projects\Company\App\Develop
ment\trunk\src\App_Tools\Signing Certificate\signtool.exe" sign /f "E:\Projects
\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Tools\Signing Certificate\Comodo_Company_Signing_Certificate.pfx" /p password /d "Company Consulti
ng" "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\obj\x86\Releas
e\App.exe" "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\bin\Re
lease\App.exe" [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073:  [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src
\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: IF EXIST %ALLUSERSPROFILE% GOTO VISTAORWIN7 [E:\Pro
jects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073:  [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src
\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: :XP [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\
src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: mkdir "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Company" [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: mkdir "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Company\Company Consulting"  [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: mkdir "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Company\Company Consulting\Modules"  [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk
\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: xcopy "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trun
k\srcApp_Shell\Modules\App.ModuleCatalog.xml" "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application D
ata\Company\Company Consulting\Modules" /S /Y [E:\Projects\Company\App
\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: xcopy "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trun
k\srcApp_Shell\Users.xml" "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Company\Company Consulting" /S /Y [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_S
hell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: GOTO END [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\t
runk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073:  [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src
\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: :VISTAORWIN7 [E:\Projects\Company\App\Developme
nt\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: mkdir "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Company" [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: mkdir "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Company\Company Cons
ulting"  [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.cspr
oj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: mkdir "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Company\Company Cons
ulting\Modules"  [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\R
oCo.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: xcopy "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trun
k\srcApp_Shell\Modules\App.ModuleCatalog.xml" "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Company\Company Consulting\Modules" /S /Y [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trun
k\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: xcopy "E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trun
k\srcApp_Shell\Users.xml" "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Company\Company Consulting"
/S /Y [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]

  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073:  [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src
\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.tar
gets(4291,5): error MSB3073: :END" exited with code 4. [E:\Projects\Company\App\Development\trunk\src\App_Shell\App.csproj]
  [msbuild]
  [msbuild]     182 Warning(s)
  [msbuild]     1 Error(s)
  [msbuild]
  [msbuild] Time Elapsed 00:01:49.45

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: MSB3073 just means that the command line returned a non zero return code. Anyways it could be many things, but this is just a wild guess. Can you take out the space in your paths and run the postbuild again? Remove the space in the "Signing Certificate" and try again. Let me know what happens

Comment: I removed the space in "Signing Certificate" and tried with no success. What is funny is that the postbuild event works in VS and if I copy and run it on command lin.

Comment: Have you tried running the msbuild via commandline withour NAnt? Test that it runs like that first.